# CSS3 Background images animation with transition

Tags: css, hover, background-image, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a two project, one with img tags and one other with div tags (background css)

my img project: http://untitledexperiment97.heliohost.org/

my div project: http://untitledexperiment97.heliohost.org/home2.html

i make 2 project because the position of circle on img project is not center to the screen, with the div project it will center to the screen :)

When i'm hover on my circle at img project the circle will rotate and scaling.

In my div project the circle won't rotate, it will just scaling. 

My quesion is, How to make it both scale and rotate on div project?


Sorry for my language :) I'm new here :) Thank you

Comment: viewed 19 times, but nobody answer :(

Comment: 132 views no body answer -_-